# How do I access the public/ files in my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just getting started on my first React app and initialized a template with [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/). I want to make a simple data visualization app. I put the data files that will be visualized into the `public/` folder but can't figure out how to access them from the application's javascript code.

I try using `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`, but it's empty. The app's code (`App.js`) is only

```
import './App.css';

function App()

  console.log(process.env.PUBLIC_URL);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <pre>app</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and the console prints nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If they're supposed to get bundled in, they don't go in your `public` dir, they're normal source code and you import them like you import anything else. If they're _not_ then you load them like any other client-side asset: by URL, using the Fetch API.

Comment: They're big files (compressed arrays) so my understanding is they shouldn't go into `src`. Why isn't the URL defined by the process.env.PUBLIC_URL? Maybe I'm just confused about what the url should be. I'm mainly coming from a scientific computing background.

Comment: the public dir is literally that: it's where URLs resolve to relative to your app. You don't need a special env var for it.

Answer (score 1):

we use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to get the `URL` to the public folder, it is empty because React now by default allows you to point directly to the public folder. For example, if you have an image folder under the public folder you can directly get the image URL string this way:

```html
<img src="/images/house.jpg" />
```

and

```html
<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/house.jpg"} />
```

is equivalent because `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` is `""`.

From your comment, it seems like your data stored are arrays so in this case you don't need them in the public folder, you can leave them there, but you have to export them so you can import them from your App component.

Comment: I see, this works when I use brackets `{}` to execute js in html elements, as you say. How should I export the arrays to import them? Ultimately I just want to read in the arrays and use the data interactively with d3.

Comment: you just do this `export const array = [...]` then `import {array} from "../location/filename"`

Answer (score 1):

You can access files in public folder directly in React.

For example:

```
<img src='/images/1.jpg' />
```

If you want to export an array of files, for example:

```
export const files = [
    "/images/1.jpg",
    "/images/2.jpg",
    "/images/3.jpg",
];
```

And then import the files array, for example:

```
import { files } from "./files"
```

To append an image to your component using `d3`, you can use `d3.select` or `d3.selectAll` to select the element where you want to add the image, and then use `append` or `insert` to create a new element.

For example:

```
const images_component = d3.select("#images-component")

files.forEach(image => {
  images_component.append("img").attr("src", image);
})
```

[You can find more details and examples to `append` and `select` using d3.](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_append)

Comment: I'm still a little confused by this... Why do I need to export an array of the file names? Why can't I just use the file names directly when I want to read the data into the app?